# Is there a non-lagrangian theory without conformal symmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry

I have been reading about the questions and answers in ([Does a non-lagrangian field theory have a stress-energy tensor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/603189/does-a-non-lagrangian-field-theory-have-a-stress-energy-tensor)) and links in thereof.

My question is the following. Are there non-Lagrangian theories without conformal symmetry?

All the theories coming from the gravity side via AdS/CFT assume that there might be a dual CFT. Are there examples of non-Lagrangian theories without it?

Examples of $\mathcal{N}=3,4$ are conformal as far as I know. Most examples of $\mathcal{N}=2$ non-Lagrangian theories are also conformal.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Whether you demand conformal invariance or not, most QFTs are non-Lagrangian. In any of the CFTs you mentioned, you can break conformal invariance by deforming with a relevant operator times a coupling constant. Do you think they will magically become Lagrangian again no matter how small the coupling is?

Comment: @ConnorBehan I think I am getting some inspriation from your answer. Thank you! The only deformation I know is to consider add something like a superpotential with a coupling constant. Is there another methods of deformation you are talking about?

Comment: Yeah, superpotentials are the deformations that will preserve at least $\mathcal{N} = 1$ supersymmetry. But there can still be a few different choices for them in https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04817 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04281 for example. Note that these papers are concerned with following the flows all the way to the IR where they lead to CFTs again but this is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much!